# Access VBA Recordset Truncation

Tags: vba, ms-access, truncation

I'm using Access 2016.  I have created a function that I've passed to a query - the function's role is to parse a memo (long text) field down from 3-4k characters (parses the string between 2 markers) to a length I can work with.  Here is the function:

```
Function getBASE(sStrx)
Dim sTemp, iBEG As Integer, iEND As Integer, sBEG As String, sEND As String
'

If InStr(UCase(sStrx), "FROM ") > 1 And InStr(sStrx, "{") > 1 Then
      iBEG = InStr(sStrx, "{") + 1
      iEND = InStr(sStrx, "}") - iBEG
      getBASE = Mid(sStrx, iBEG, iEND)
End If
'
End Function
```

The resultant length of this is around 700 characters.  When I create a LEN on the result, I get 700 chars.  I then run a sub (code below) that contains a Split function, but the result of the split is 255 characters.  However, I have a couple of msgbox's that pop up to check the length of the recordset value and it's 700 (the correct length), but for some reason, it's truncating.  I don't know if this is due the function, the sub, or something else.  One other thing:  I can pass the original value (3-4k chars) to the sub and it works fine.  I'm beyond frustrated...thx for the help.

```
Sub Break_String()
  Dim db As DAO.Database, rsSource As DAO.Recordset, rsDest As DAO.Recordset
  Set db = CurrentDb()
  Set rsSource = db.OpenRecordset("qTEST")
  Set rsDest = db.OpenRecordset("tblParsed")
  Dim WrdArray() As String
  rsSource.MoveFirst
  WrdArray() = Split(UCase(rsSource("[getBASE]")), "FROM ")
  '
  MsgBox Len(rsSource("[getBASE]")) <---- 700 chars

  For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
   strg = strg & vbNewLine & WrdArray(i)
  Next i
  '
  MsgBox strg    <----- 255 chars
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` and/or the Watch window to see your variables while stepping through your code. See [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: You would expect `strg` to be shorter than `rsSource("[getBASE]")` due to replacing 5 characters with 2 characters.  255 characters is what you would expect if you had 149 occurrences of `"FROM "` in the source.  I assume you have checked that that isn't the reason.  (BTW - is your splitting and rejoining of the strings just equivalent to `vbNewLine & Replace(UCase(rsSource("[getBASE]")), "FROM ", vbNewLine)`?)

Comment: @Andre:  Yes, have checked this.  Don't think it has to do with the function, because the sub measures the length of the passed recordset correctly.  I think it may the be the "split" function.  FYI, I'm parsing email header data (looking for instances of the phrase "FROM ".  The example above has 4 instances.  But when I debug.print the LBound and Ubound values, I get 0 and 2 (not 0 and 4, which is what I would expect).  Funny thing is, when I run the sub against the original 4k length string, it works (i.e., splits string at all 4 "FROM " markers).

Comment: Did you try the Replace suggested by YowE3K? Eliminate the Split and concatenation.

Comment: Yes...can't quite get it.  I've moved this project over to SQL with string parsing markers (begin, end) and a split TVF, which is what I should have done to begin with.  Access Jet seems to have a mind of its' own sometimes.  Thanks for all the assistance.